# Improve the url mangling of special character combinations (like C++, c#, ...)

Tags: feature-request, usability, hyperlinks

The URL to post that contains C++ in the subject are mangled as C.

I really like the feature that appends the mangled title to the post id since it enable to fast-read it.

But often I get fooled by a link being mangled as C and the original title means C++, or C# like this one :
[C++ "multiple types in one declaration" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753189/c-multiple-types-in-one-declaration-error) that means "*C++ multiple types in one declaration error*" ?

Would it be possible to include a sort of "stop-words" that would be specially mangled ?

For example `c++` would be mangled to `cpp`, `c#` to `csharp`, ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753189/c++-multiple-types-in-one-declaration-error - works! :)

Comment: I know. I just don't want to have to edit them manually when copy/pasting...

Comment: @John Smithers: of course, because the url is shortened, we don't see how your link is different until we hover. :)

Comment: Just click it, Kip :)

Comment: I think you meant `c#` to `dflat`....