# Slugs generated for C# Should Include "c-sharp"

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, slug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improve the url mangling of special character combinations (like C++, c#, …)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30182/improve-the-url-mangling-of-special-character-combinations-like-c-c)

StackOverflow generates a slug for the URL based on the title of your question.

e.g. "Best naming for a property in C#?" becomes [Best naming for a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878484/best-naming-for-a-property-in-c)

I'd like to see the slugs generated for C# to read "c-sharp" instead of "c".  e.g.
[Best naming for a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878484/best-naming-for-a-property-in-c-sharp)

This would make it clear in the URL that I'm talking about C# and not C.

Comment: I'd add `C++`/`cpp` and `F#`/`f-sharp`.

Comment: I think you mean `d-flat`.